# What influence was present to convince Israel to accept the Babylonian Talmud as the basis to Halacha?

Tags: halacha, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi, geonim

In the times of the Gaonim, [Yehudai Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehudai_ben_Nahman) and [Pirqoi ben Baboi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirqoi_ben_Baboi) seem to have tried to convince Israel to follow the Babylonian Talmud in the wake of earliest codified halachic works.

What other influence was present to move Israel (who presumably were following the Jerusalem/Yerushalmi Talmud at the time) to accept the Babylonian/Bavli Talmud? And how did they respond to this push?

Comment: Dying out played a large role. There was an active Israeli tradition until they were essentially destroyed (by the crusades?).

Comment: Your assumption is not true. The Babylonian academies were the preeminent religious authorities after Byzantine persecution destroyed the Jerusalem academies, so naturally they were followed.

Comment: @N.T. Which assumption? The letter of Pirqoi ben Baboi seems to be well known, and clearly Jews in Israel were not following the Babylonian tradition - hence the letter.

Comment: The letter is not well known in official histories. It was discovered in the Cairo genizah. Maybe there were some outlier communities (as there always are), but all sages from the post-Talmudic era rule based on the Babylonian Talmud.

Comment: @N.T. Clearly there was a switch somewhere (as they previously used the Jerusalem Talmud), so if it happened earlier, it would be good to have sources to that effect. Could you provide examples of major early geonim (or prior) in Israel that used the Babylonian Talmud as the basis for Halacha? The sources I've seen are all outside Israel claiming that Israel already accepted it. To add, when *was* Israel persuaded to use the Babylonian Talmud?

Comment: ואינן חייבין לשמור כ"א יום אחד בין בר"ה בין בשאר ימים טובים וכן נהגו לעשות בא"י כל הדורות שהיו לפנינו עד עתה חדשים מקרוב באו לשם מחכמי פרובינציאה והנהיגום לעשות שני ימים טובים בר"ה על פי הלכות הרי"ף ז"ל
https://www.sefaria.org.il/HaMaor_HaKatan_on_Beitzah.2b.3?lang=bi

Comment: @JoelK Could you kindly expand on this a bit? My (weak) understanding is that this take wants the jews of Israel to observe two days rather than one day of Rosh Hashana in Israel, given there is a set calendar (?). The RiF lived much later, closer to the time of Rambam, but this is a question of kedushat Erez Yisroel, not Bavli vs Yerushalmi tradition (unless I'm reading it wrong?).

Comment: It's not directly answering your question, which is why it's only a comment. Just pointing out that there seem to have been Provencal scholars who came to Israel in the 11th or 12th centuries and prevailed on them to change their practice, from originally keeping only one day RH to keeping two. (That Israelis should keep 2 days RH is a Babylonian position (although not explicit in the Talmud Bavli itself) - R Hai Gaon is quoted in this same piece of Ba'al HaMaor as ruling this way.)